# the issue about the ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, oracle

my database is oracle ,the oracle charset is "us7ascii".and i save chinese charset in the database ,normally ,i get the data from the database ,use

`Statement s =conn.createStatement();`

then execute the sql, then use

`new String (string.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"gbk")`

i can get the correct data.but if i use:

`Statement s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`

still use:

`new String (string.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"gbk")`

convert the encode,but i can't get the correct data ,the result is "?????" ,why ?